# How should I react to serial downvoting?

Tags: support, voting

Today someone went thru all my questions and downvoted theme. I got notification about 16 of my questions been downvoted here and few there.

It happened after VZN asked me to vote for him in the Moderator elections for theoretical computer science site. I wanted to but I need 150 rep for that, and I don't have it now.

I think that someone else who don't want him to be elected did this.

Can someone contact StackExchange staff to investigate this?

Comment: As far as I see it, the cold fact is that everyone is entitled to their opinion and can vote exactly as they please. Not saying it is nice or respectful either perhaps, but votes are also not permanent. Perhaps by improving your questions the downvoter will upvote instead, or other people can upvote your questions!

Comment: Reputation *here* does not affect the elections on [cstheory.SE] so it's unlikely somebody tried to influence the elections that way.

Comment: hi B. thx for dropping by and sorry to hear of your experience, it has happened to me a few times over the many months on the site also & it is not uncommon on stackexchange. the way to look at points is that they tend to oscillate a bit, and when new people show up to read your posts, or the posts get new attn based on some chg on the site (for example linked to another active post) there can be new activity. if a post ever got downvotes in the past, it has some chance of getting them in the future. the same principle works for upvotes & the oldtimers get upvotes on old posts routinely....

Answer (score 8):

You have had many posts downvoted in a short span of time today. Assuming these votes were all cast by the same user, they will be reverted automatically. Since this is done by a nightly job, wait 24 hours. If the votes are still there after more than 24 hours, use the [contact form](https://cs.stackexchange.com/contact) and explain the issue (moderators don't know who voted for what, but some Stack Exchange staff do, so you might as well contact them directly).

For more information about serial voting, see [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) on the main meta site.

This won't affect your ability to vote in the CSTheory elections. You didn't have 150 reputation there in the first place, so you wouldn't have been able to vote anyway.

You tend to ask a lot of questions that are unclear, that are long, imprecise attempts at a proof, or that denote a lack of knowledge of the field you are trying to find new results in. All of these are legitimate reasons for downvotes. It is doubtful that these votes are related to the ongoing election, especially since they wouldn't influence it in any way. Nonetheless, going through a user's profile and downvoting many of their posts is not appropriate behavior, even if you genuinely think each post deserves a downvote — the only rule about voting is that you must not target a user. This goes equally for upvotes. This is why serial downvoting is automatically reversed.